# I have a question about matching the first 5 digits in a string in a regular expression

Tags: numbers, range

I would like to limit a string of numbers to 14 digits, and require that the first 5 digits are: 26173. The rest of the digits can be any number between 1-9. Example: 26173000740380.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

The regexp `26173\d{9}` specifies the first 5 characters must be `26173` and the following 9 characters must be any decimal number `\d`.

If the remaining 9 characters must be between 1 - 9 you could use `26173[1-9]{9}`.  Both examples are using java regexp syntax.

Regexp planet is a good site for testing regular expressions

https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html